# RegExp#match returns only one match

Tags: ruby, regex, pcre

Explain me, please, why `match()` returns only one match, instead of four (for example):

```
s = 'aaaa'
p /a/.match(s).to_a # => ["a"]
```

It is stranger that with grouping `match()` return two matches, independently of real matches count:

```
s = 'aaaa'
p /(a)/.match(s).to_a # => ["a", "a"]

s = 'a aaa a'
p /(a)/.match(s).to_a # => ["a", "a"]
```

Thank for yours answers.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about `Regexp#math`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `.scan()` to match more than once:

```
p s.scan(/a/).to_a
```

And with grouping, you get one result for the overall match, and one for each group (when using `.match()`. Both results are the same in your regex.

Some examples:

```
> /(a)/.matc­h(s).to_a
=> ["a", "a"]           # First: Group 0 (overall match), second: Group 1
> /(a)+/.mat­ch(s).to_a­
=> ["aaaa", "a"]        # Regex matches entire string, group 1 matches the last a
> s.scan(/a/­).to_a
=> ["a", "a", "a", "a"] # Four matches, no groups
> s.scan(/(a­)/).to_a
=> [["a"], ["a"], ["a"], ["a"]] # Four matches, each containing one group
> s.scan(/(a­)+/).to_a
=> [["a"]]              # One match, the last match of group 1 is retained
> s.scan(/(a­+)(a)/).to­_a
=> [["aaa", "a"]]       # First group matches aaa, second group matches final a
> s.scan(/(a­)(a)/).to_­a
=> [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"]] # Two matches, both group participate once per match
```

Answer (score 3):

By feature, `match` only matches once. A single match corresponds to a `MatchData` instance, and `MatchData#to_a` returns an array where the 0th element is the whole match, and the other n-th elements are the n-th captures, respectively. A capture is whatever that matches inside `()`. If you do not have any `()` in the regex, then the array would only have the whole match.

The reason there is more than one `"a"` in `["a", "a"]` with `/(a)/` is because a single match has a capture in addition to the whole match: The first `"a"` represents the whole match, corresponding to `/(a)/`, and the second `"a"` represents the first capture, corresponding to the `a` inside `(a)`.

If you wanted to match arbitrary many matches, use `scan`.